# Stylesheet not responding in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I am linking my external CSS file to the HTML file but the code doesn't seem to be in effect, even tried changing the order for the bootstrap style to load first.
HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

<body>

  <section id="title">
</head>
```

CSS FILE:

```
#title{
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your stylesheet is where you say it is?  Maybe you should show us the directory structure,

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the reference of your css file path. It is not getting the CSS file.

It will be like below.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: can you share your directory structure. I used  the same code its working for me. Directory structure is : "Desktop\sections\stylecheck.html" (html path) and stylesheet path "Desktop\sections\css\style.css"